# Is there a way to know if the user is using a small device similar to flexbox using col-sm?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, bootstrap-4

I was wondering if there is a way to know if the user is using a small device.  I want my navigation menu to change if the user is using a small device or if he is using a desktop.  I want it to be similar to col-sm

Comment: You're looking for [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use CSS media queries for the responsive website or different size of devices. You can use CSS as according to mobile orientation also.

```
<style>

    /* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {  

       /* Your CSS Code for this device size */    

      }

    /* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
    @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {  

       /* Your CSS Code for this device size */    

    }

    /* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {  

       /* Your CSS Code for this device size */    

    } 

    /* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
    @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {  

       /* Your CSS Code for this device size */    

    }      

    /* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {

       /* Your CSS Code for this device size */ 

    }

   /* According to Mobile Orientation */
   @media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {   

       /* Your CSS Code for this device orientation */    

   }

  </style>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what `@media` queries are used for in CSS.

```
@media screen and (max-width:479px) {
    .navbar {
        // style of .navbar when screen is less than 479px
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:480px) {
    .navbar {
        // style of .navbar when screen is 480px or larger
    }
}
```